# Where and how to set the LANGUAGE_CODE in a Django application?

Tags: django, internationalization

I'm given a Django application, [WebODM](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/WebODM/tree/master/app) and I need to set its application-wide language to the Turkish language.

The Turkish translation files (with the endings .po) are all in place. When a browser whose default language is Turkish is used, the app displays Turkish. When any other browser, whose language is not set is used, the app displays English. I need to make the app display always Turkish whichever browser is used.

I start the app with its own start script inside Docker and it starts fine.

I've read the official Django documentation (which ise over 2000 pages) and there it talks about setting `LANGUAGE_CODE` variable e.g. `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'tr-tr` but it doesn't talk about exactly where and how to set it. It talks about a file called `settings.py` but it doesn't mention under which directory it resides

I've searched the application's root directory for  `settings.py` and those two files came up

```
<root-dir>/contexts/settings.py
<root-dir>/templatetags/settings.py
```

But inside them were like:

```
import logging

from app.models import Setting

logger = logging.getLogger('app.logger')

# Make the SETTINGS object available to all templates
def load(request=None):
    return {'SETTINGS': Setting.objects.first()}

# Helper functions for libsass

def theme(color):
    """Return a theme color from the currently selected theme"""
    try:
<truncate>
```

i.e. plain Python code so I haven't put a random `LANGUAGE_CODE` into any of those two `settings.py` files. I've created instead a `settings.py` under the root directory and put `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'tr-tr` into it and restarted the application but it didn't change the application-wide language at all.

So where and how to set the `LANGUAGE_CODE` in this Django application to be able to set the *application-wide* language?

Comment: What is your project structure? How did you create the project? How do you run it?

Comment: @GwynBleidD it's this Open Source app [WebODM](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/WebODM) i.e. it's ready made. The Turkish translation files (with the ending `.po`) are all in place and they do work fine as long as a browser whose default lang is Turkish opens the app. I run the app with its own start script.

Comment: the file you're looking for is located at `webodm/settings.py`